# «Отымется» — есть ли такое слово?

Tags: лексика

**Отымется** (в значении "отнимется") — есть ли такое слово или это просторечная форма?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет такого слова. )))
Я бы даже просторечием не назвал. Просто ненормативность.

Вот слово отымать вместо отнимать словарями фиксируется, но именно как просторечие, причем устаревающее.

Answer (score 3):

> ...есть ли такое слово?

**Есть.** В *"Большом академическом словаре"* (2011 г.) даётся с пометами "устарелое" и "просторечное".

Когда-то таковым не являлось. Употреблял его и Пушкин:

> *Когда же юность легким дымом*
>
> *Умчит веселья юных дней,*
>
> *Тогда у старости отымем*
>
> *Всё, что **отымется** у ней.*
>
> [А. С. Пушкин. Добрый совет (1817-1820)]